# Javascript: I think I am attempting to use an event triggered from a form button with conditional values set from a radio button...?

Tags: javascript

Well, the goal is to make the radio button true or false trigger an event that causes text corresponding to the message appear. I have failed. If you'd rather solve the problem than explain what i did wrong, that's ok too. I understand you're all busy. I'm trying very hard to learn, and if you are willing to explain what I did wrong, so I can better understand JavaScript syntax and logic, I would really appreciate it! 
https://codepen.io/Slimmwillis/pen/WMRmJP

```js
var x = 3;
var y = 2;
var z = x + y;

document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = z;

function myFunction() {
  var OnSubmit;
  var clicked = new Boolean().getvalue();
  /* I think the error is I am failing to get a value for clicked from Boolean which I believe is declared as either false or true in the form above. Help me Sensei!*/
  if (clicked == true) {
    OnSubmit = "That is correct, you know Maths";
  } else if (clicked == false) {
    OnSubmit = "Incorrect! Dummy!";
  } else {
    OnSubmit = "Please Select 1";
  }
  document.getElementById("clicker").innerHTML = OnSubmit;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>So easy I could cry</h1>
  <p>3+2=</p>
  <!-- displays the result of x+y-->
  <p id="num"></p>
  <!-- True of False form-->

  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="Boolean" value="true" checked> True<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Boolean" value="false"> False<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <!-- The if.. elseif...else statement-->
    <h2> So hard I could Cry</h2>

    <p id="clicker"></p>
    
  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and then correct this question.

Comment: I just forgot to link the code. I literally just posted this. Far as I know that was the only problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- You need to bind the `submit` event to your `form` to call your function `myFunction`.

```
document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', myFunction);
```

- To get the boolean value of `clicked`, execute the following selector `[name="Boolean"]:checked` to get the checked readiobutton:

```
document.querySelectorAll('[name="Boolean"]:checked').forEach(function(e) {
    clicked = e.getAttribute('value') === 'true';
});
```

```js
var x = 3;
var y = 2;
var z = x + y;

document.getElementById("num").innerHTML = z;
var clicker = document.getElementById("clicker")

function myFunction(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // remove this if you need to submit that form.
  var onSubmit,
      clicked;

  document.querySelectorAll('[name="Boolean"]:checked').forEach(function(e) {
    clicked = e.getAttribute('value') === 'true';
  });

  /* I think the error is I am failing to get a value for clicked from Boolean which I believe is declared as either false or true in the form above. Help me Sensei!*/

  if (clicked) {
    onSubmit = "That is correct, you know Maths";
  } else if (!clicked) {
    onSubmit = "Incorrect! Dummy!";
  } else {
    onSubmit = "Please Select 1";
  }

  clicker.innerHTML = onSubmit;
}

document.querySelector('form').addEventListener('submit', myFunction);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<body>

  <h1>So easy I could cry</h1>
  <p>3+2=</p>
  <!-- displays the result of x+y-->
  <p id="num"></p>
  <!-- True of False form-->

  <form>
    <input type="radio" name="Boolean" value="true" checked> True<br>
    <input type="radio" name="Boolean" value="false"> False<br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    <!-- The if.. elseif...else statement-->
    <h2> So hard I could Cry</h2>

    <p id="clicker"></p>

  </form>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: dude, THANK YOU SO VERY MUCH! I will stare at and study the crap outta this. 1337 o7

Comment: it works flawless! but as I dissect this I am sitting here like 'why does this work' lol. So the first pondering I come upon is 'How does Javascript realize which submit event to bind to which of my forms to call my function, myFunction? It doesn't seem to have any id tags, to specify. I assume with only 1 of each it wouldn't be hard to pull off, but if there was 2 of either, if even possible, how would javascript know which events and forms to bind to create myFunction? Or if it knows because it exists within the block or scope of the code?
 but It's not with in the scope!

Answer (score 0):

You can use jquery API its quite simple:

```
<form class='myform'>
    <input type='radio' id='myRadioBox'>
</form>
$(document).ready(function(){
     $('.myform').submit(function(event){
         event.preventDefault();
         var result = document.getElementById('myRadioBox').value;
         if(result == 'checked'){
             // display true/false message
         }else{
             // display false/true message
         }
     })
});
```

'event.preventDefault()' is to prevent the form from submitting! you should always include it if you are checking for a condition before submitting a form, thereafter you can submit the form!

```
$('.myform').submit();
```

Comment: Having just one radio button makes no sense, they come in groups, and you need to tell which one is selected.

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH!!!!! I've learned something new! although this maybe easy for you, as someone who studied php with no javascript, this is very difficult for me. I am trying very hard though. Please forgive my shortcomings.

Answer (score 0):

make the radio buttons have a single class the iterate the class and check for your condition along! i.e

```
for(var i=0; i<radioClass.length; i++){
      if(result == checked){
         // do something
      }else{
         // do something else!
      }
}
var result = document.getElementByClassName('radioClass');
// result will be an array of radio buttons;
```